# How to work around type parameter of class shadowed by method

Tags: scala

With the following code, >= and <= methods are using implicit parameter and context bound, which are essentially the same.

```
@Test
def testOrdering(): Unit = {
  class Box[T](val data: T) {
    def >= (that: Box[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Boolean = {
      val comp = ord.compare(data, that.data)
      comp >= 0
    }
    def <=[T :Ordering] (that: Box[T]): Boolean = {
      val ord = implicitly[Ordering[T]]
      //compile error in the following code
      val comp = ord.compare(data, that.data)
      comp <= 0
    }
  }
}
```

However, the T in the <= method is different from the T defined in Box[T], so there is compiling error in <=.(`val comp = ord.compare(data, that.data)`, data and that.data are different types.)

I would ask if it is possible to around around this problem:

(1)T is defined in Box[T]

(2)Using context bound in the method, like <=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `>=` is how you do it.

```
def <= (that: Box[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Boolean = {
  val comp = ord.compare(data, that.data)
  comp <= 0
}
```

Shadowing `T` will never work here, because you are telling the compiler there is a *another* type parameter than the `T` defined in `Box[T]`, even if it has the same name. And you can only use the context bound syntax at the definition site of a type parameter.

Comment: Thanks @michael-zajac. It looks to me that this is a case when we can only use implicit parameter other than context bound or view bound

Comment: @Tom Oh you could work around it and do it with a context bound but it would just be silly.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper-M for the reply. Yes, it should be silly, :-). Could you provide some code to demonstrate how to work round this?

Answer (score 1):

You could still use a context bound if you add a type alias `type OrderingT[A] = Ordering[T]`. Notice how the type parameter `A` basically gets thrown away. But then of course you'll add a useless type parameter (in this example named `_`) to every method.

```
def testOrdering(): Unit = {
  class Box[T](val data: T) {
    type OrderingT[A] = Ordering[T]

    def >=[_: OrderingT](that: Box[T]): Boolean = {
      val comp = Ordering[T].compare(data, that.data)
      comp >= 0
    }
    def <=[_: OrderingT](that: Box[T]): Boolean = {
      val comp = Ordering[T].compare(data, that.data)
      comp <= 0
    }

  }
}
```